# Small delays in SQL queries

Tags: mysql, iis-10

I am trying to troubleshoot why some of our backoffice pages (and some frontend with categories containing many products) takes a bit too long to load. Each sql in the queries that are used aren't that intense, but there seems to be microdelays every so often which causes problems.

An example I am working on now is checking if all products of a store have language translations (and a few other things). While each product takes a rather short time, we have over a thousand products, and together it stacks up since there are a few queries that happens for each product.

Here is a small testcode I created in ASP classic (which is the language we are using). It's basically a loop that loads a query and puts the product description into a variable for the same product over and over 1000 times and writes out the current time for each loop.

```
sql = _
"SELECT language_prod_desc " &_
"  FROM language_prod " &_
" WHERE language_prod_pid = 30761462 " &_
"   AND language_prod_lang = 'no' "

for i = 0 to 1000
    set rs = cn.execute(SQL)
    desc = rs("language_prod_desc").value
    response.write (10000+i) & "<strong>  " & mid(timer(),3,6) & "</strong><br>"
next
```

Here is a small sample of the output to show that there are sometimes small 0.02s delays in the loops.

```
10000 296,39
10001 296,39
10002 296,39
10003 296,39
10004 296,39
10005 296,41 <---
10006 296,41
10007 296,41
10008 296,41
10009 296,41
10010 296,41
10011 296,41
10012 296,41
10013 296,41
10014 296,41
10015 296,41
10016 296,41
10017 296,43 <---
10018 296,43
10019 296,43
10020 296,43
10021 296,43
10022 296,43
```

I am using IIS10, running MySQL 5.0.12.

**Question:** What could be causing these "microdelays" or how could I go about troubleshooting what is causing them?

Comment: Could it be round tripping to the server for another buffer?

Comment: While I think this question is good and deserves to stand since this is not-so-great behavior... I would REALLY question a design where you implement a select statement inside of a loop to get back info on ~1000 products. A giant in-list, while not-so-awesome, would still be a drastic improvement over a loop.

Comment: In practice, I think delays of that magnitude are inevitable in queries to an external database, just from the round-trip of going to the DB and back. Like @JNevill said, I think the best solution is to re-work this into a single query.

Comment: Also, are we talking 0.02s (20 milliseconds) or 0.002s (2 milliseconds)?

Comment: Because of poor database design of the former sysdev, and the data being too integrated in too many functions, and a lack of support from management for doing an overhaul since it will take too many resources short term. I don't think I can at this moment rework the query to include all the things I need to check at the same time, but I will definitely improve upon it.

Comment: It is 0.02seconds (20 milliseconds), so the delay is rather huge. 28 seconds to load the entire page at the moment because it's fetching bits of information in many small queries.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Is there any way to check this? Why would it only happen every ~10th loop?

Comment: Could you see if you get the exact same delays when querying with a random (or at least different) ID each time? It could be that it's locally buffering the results, since you're sending the same query each time, and only actually talking to the DB every couple iterations (in case the DB data changed). Honestly, the 0 delay queries are the odd one out here; I would expect some amount of time-delay after every query.

Comment: Another thing to check is the accuracy of your timer function. It could be that every query is taking a uniform amount of time, and your timer function is just rounding the results. I'd be interested to see what the timer output is if you do the exact same loop minus the query and with a very small `sleep`.

Comment: Your test code probably doesn't teach us much, because of the query cache. It's not strange to see, occasionally, a few seconds' delay in operations in databases that have been around for a while. That is especially true if you have several different queries (from different users?) hitting the database concurrently. You might try using `OPTIMIZE TABLE xxxx;` on your tables. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html Back up your database first, and do this during off hours.

Comment: @JoshEller Thanks for the input. The problems happens over all IDs, and is showing up on different IDs on each run through when running it live. This test was to eliminate any possible variations from different data. I rewrote the time-script to show milliseconds and at only one spot did the milliseconds move only one digit, the rest of the time it jumped only when the "big" jumps occurs, so you may be right in the accuracy of it.

Comment: Did some optimisation in queries and added more stuff to check for with joins, and still managed to get it down to 12 seconds to load for a store with just over 1500 products. I guess optimisation is the biggest keyword here, even though I find the behaviour a bit strange in my test example. Is 12 seconds acceptable for 1500 products? Probably close enough for a page that a couple of translators load every once in a while to check that everything looks ok.